# Scanner Class - hasNextDouble()

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

can someone tell me why when I am typing `inputDouble`(as a double of course), a conditional doesn't let me pass. I tried this also on float type and result is the same.

**EDIT: Conditional passing when I'm typing integer.**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner inputDouble = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Double");

    if(inputDouble.hasNextDouble()){
        System.out.println("Passed");
    }

    inputDouble.close();

}
```

Thanks for help.

**SOLVED: CODE WAS GOOD I WAS TYPING INPUT WITH DOT INSTEAD OF COMMA**

Comment: I tested the code and passed the condition.

Comment: can you show the value you're passing in?

Comment: Maybe your locale expects different format for double then you provided. Try with `1.2` or `1,2`.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw - `12.234214343245`, `12.1` and `12` have been used.

Comment: @Farahmand all those work for me, this could be to do with locality.

Comment: Pshemo thanks, it should be written with comma

Answer (score 0):

> Conditional passing when I'm typing integer.

this is known as widening the type, basically, an `int` type can be converted to a `double` type safely without any loss of data. The compiler implicitly converts the `int` to a `double` type.

as for:

> can someone tell me why when I am typing inputDouble(as a double of
>   course), a conditional doesn't let me pass.

As far as I know there is no problem with your code as I have tested it on my IDE and everything seems to be working as expected. However, this could be to do with locality, so make sure that you are using the correct locale for the `Scanner`.

try using `,` as the delimiter for double/decimal values rather than `.`

Comment: But I still don't know why conditional doesn't pass for example 3.0